# ksh command subsitution with quotes into array

Tags: java, shell, scripting, ksh

I have a Java class with the following output:

```
"Roses are red" "Violets are blue" "Daisies are white"
```

I am trying to create a KornShell (ksh) script that executes this Java class, stores the result into an array, and then outputs

```
Roses are red
Violets are blue
Daises are white
```

This is my first attempt at the script:

```
1 #!/bin/ksh
2 
3 set -A colors $(java Colors)
4 
5 for i in "${colors[@]}"
6 do
7     echo "$i"
8 done
```

However, the output looks like this:

```
"Roses
are
Red"
"Violets
are
blue"
"Daisies
are
white"
```

When I throw:

```
echo set -A colors $(java Colors)
```

into the script to see what is being called, it returns:

```
set -A colors "Roses are Red" "Violets are blue" "Daisies are white"
```

If I replace that exact output with line 3 from above, I get the desired output:

```
Roses are red
Violets are blue
Daises are white
```

Why does the command substitution throw the whole thing off?

Below is the Java class if that helps:

```
public class Colors {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\"Roses are Red\" \"Violets are blue\" \"Daisies are white\"");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up making it work by throwing an 'eval' in front of the set command. It looked like this:

```
1 #!/bin/ksh
2 
3 eval set -A colors $(java Colors)
4 
5 for i in "${colors[@]}"
6 do
7     echo "$i"
8 done
```

I'm not sure why that worked exactly, but it did.

Comment: Parsing a command line requires many stages. Prepending `eval` gives ksh a second chance at processing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use quotes on `$( )` :

```
set -A colors "$(java Colors)"
```

to avoid *word splitting*

Comment: I've tried that, but then the output just looks like `"Roses are Red" "Violets are blue" "Daisies are white"`, all on one line.

Answer (score 0):

pass the output of your java command as arguments to another shell script.

Then it will give $1=>"Roses are red",$2=>"Violets are blue", and so on.

you can get hold of all the input arguments using $@

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing is distressingly hard to do.  This seems to work:

```
$ cat roses
echo '"Roses are red" "Violets are blue" "Daisies are white"'
$ IFS='
> '                                       
$ set -A colors $(eval printf '%s\\n' $(./roses))
$ printf "%s\n" "${colors[@]}"                   
Roses are red
Violets are blue
Daisies are white
$
```

The script `./roses` does the same job as your Java class.  The variable `IFS` is the inter-field separator string; it is set to a newline (only).  The `set` line creates an array `colors`.  The value is what you get from executing and capturing `eval printf '%s\\n' $(./roses)`.  The second `printf` statement prints the elements of the array one per line.

Tested with `ksh` on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

An equivalent in `bash` is:

```
$ IFS='
> '
$ colors=($(eval printf '%s\\n' $(./roses)))
$ printf "%s\n" "${colors[@]}"
Roses are red
Violets are blue
Daisies are white
$
```

Depending a bit on the version of [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays), there are probably other ways to do it too.

You should save and restore the value of `$IFS` before trampling it.

```
$ old_ifs="$IFS"
$ IFS='
> '
$ ...use the modified value...
$ IFS="$old_ifs"
$
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the trick was to use `eval`, but I'm not sure why. What exactly does `eval` do?